# Navigation Bar hide not working in SwiftUI iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am using xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15,i want to hide the navigational bar and the back arrow i have tried several methods. none of the answers worked

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ZStack{
                Text("Header") //Header View
                Spacer ()
                Text("Main")//Main View
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                Text("Bottom") //Bottom View
        }.navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
    }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate this on my Xcode 13.2.1 using iOS 15.2 – checked on both iOS and iPadOS simulators

Comment: Any chance your View is embedded in another NavigationView with title: e.g: `NavigationView{BuggedView().navigationTitle("my title")}`

Comment: using a `ZStack` does not make sense, it should be VStack. Are you sure this is the code that replicates your problem.

Comment: .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
 you can add this here

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed this on xcode 12.5 by adding this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true // <== ADD THIS LINE
        return true
    }
}
```

and then under info.plist I added

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

using xml type.

Also I had `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on the upmost level in the view, so for you, the NavigationView.

Answer (score 1):

A better SwiftUI approach is to create a @State property to toggle the state.

```
@State private var hideNavigationbar: Bool = false
```

You switching the value in **.onAppear {}** to true. When you dismiss the view you call **.onDisappear {}** and set the property to false.

Now you can use it like so:

```
.navigationbarHidden(hideNavigationbar)
```